# Can someone tell me if my doorbell wiring is low voltage?

Tags: power-supply, transistors

I've not seen a pink and black wire-combo. Does that mean it's low voltage?
here is a pic...[image: doorbell]

Comment: If you look at your electrical panel there's a good chance you'll find a "doorbell transformer" attached.  If you locate it, it should be marked with its voltage rating.  You can also check with a digital multimeter.

Comment: Most common was a 24 Vac “doorbell”transformer.

Answer (score 3):

You should not rely on wire color to indicate voltage but yes, that doorbell is low voltage (<50 V). If there is any doubt, measure it with a meter.